# Learning Haskell: How to remove an item from a List in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Trying to learn Haskell. I am trying to write a simple function to remove a number from a list without using built-in function (delete...I think). For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the input parameter is an Integer and the list is an Integer list. Here is the code I have, Please tell me what's wrong with the following code

```
areTheySame :: Int -> Int-> [Int]

areTheySame x y | x == y = []
                | otherwise = [y]

removeItem :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]

removeItem x (y:ys) = areTheySame x y : removeItem x ys
```

Comment: Just as a tip, cracking open the Haskell 98 report and reading the code provided for the Prelude functions is a real eye-opener.  You'll learn a lot about how things work (and learn a lot about things you shouldn't bother doing yourself except as an intellectual learning exercise!).  Here's a decent tour of it: http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/172/Haskell/tourofprelude.html.  http://members.chello.nl/hjgtuyl/tourdemonad.html and http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp1100/haskell/tourofsyntax.html are also helpful.  (Sadly haskell.org is still down so I can't hook you up with the report directly.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The others are right that the problem is the `:` operator. I would say that your `areTheySame` function that returns a list is the wrong approach anyway, though. Rather than switch to the `++` operator, a better implementation of that function would be:

```
removeItem _ []                 = []
removeItem x (y:ys) | x == y    = removeItem x ys
                    | otherwise = y : removeItem x ys
```

As you can see, this is a pretty simple implementation. Also, consing like this is much less taxing for your program than appending a bunch of lists together. It has other benefits as well, such as working lazily.

Answer (score 11):

The `:` operator doesn't do what you think it does:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

It takes an item of type `a` and adds it to the beginning of a list of type `a`. You're using it to join two lists of type `a`. For that, you need to use `++`:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Also, if you make a recursive function, it needs an ending condition. So try this:

```
removeItem _ [] = []
removeItem x (y:ys) = areTheySame x y ++ removeItem x ys
```

That way, when you get to the end of the list, the function will stop recursing.

Comment: If you actually apply your explanation to your code and change the last `:` for an `++` your code would be correct, currently it's producing lists of lists (`areTheySame` always returns a list and you add this to the beginning of a list using `:`).

Comment: If you keep the original type definition, you get a type error.

Comment: You're right - I copied his line and forgot to change the part I had just talked about changing. Either way, it's probably not the best way to do things, but it certainly works.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this as a list-comprehension

```
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete deleted xs = [ x | x <- xs, x /= deleted ]
```

Comment: albeit this might be a bit slower

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a function in just one line of code:

```
remove element list = filter (\e -> e/=element) list
```

For example:

```
remove 5 [1..10]
```

[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]

```
remove 'b' ['a'..'f']
```

"acdef"

Comment: You don’t need the lambda here `filter (/=element) list`

Answer (score 4):

This is the minimal fix to make your example work:

```
removeItem :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeItem _ []     = []
removeItem x (y:ys) = areTheySame x y ++ removeItem x ys
```

First, you need to use `++` to concatenate lists, as the `:` operator used by you adds just one element to the beginning of a list (it can neither be used to add lists with one element nor to add empty lists). You first compare the head of the list (`y`) to the item you want to remove and correctly return the item or an empty list using `areTheySame`. Then you want to recursively continue using `removeItem` on the rest of the list (`ys`). The resulting list needs to be concatenated using `++`.

Second, as Chris Lutz noted, you need an ending condition when you reach the end of the list. By adding this line, Haskell knows what to do with an empty list (that is, nothing, just return an empty list).

As Chuck said, you can simplify the code for this task by having removeItem not delegate the task of the comparison, but compare itself and throw away the element if it should be removed, otherwise keep it at the list head (using `:`). In any case, continue recursively with the rest of the list.

```
-- nothing can be removed from an empty list
-- ==> return empty list and stop recursion
removeItem _ []     = []

-- if the list is not empty, cut off the head in y and keep the rest in ys
--                    if x==y, remove y and continue
removeItem x (y:ys) | x == y    = removeItem x ys    
--                    otherwise, add y back and continue 
                    | otherwise = y : removeItem x ys
```

Answer (score 3):

For reference, you may be interested in seeing [how it's done in `delete` from Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#delete).

You could leave `areTheySame` as is, but you'd then need to use [`concatMap`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3AconcatMap) in `removeItem` to collapse the empty lists:

```
removeItem :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeItem x xs = concatMap (areTheySame x) xs
```

or equivalently

```
removeItem :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeItem x = concatMap (areTheySame x)
```

Note that the types of your functions could be more general:

```
areTheySame :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a]
removeItem  :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

This allows removal of items from lists of any type for which `==` is defined, not just `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the solutions given so far work differently than Data.List.delete, which only deletes the first member.

```
deleteFromList x xs =
  case break (==x) xs of
    (_,[]) -> xs
    (notsat,sat) -> notsat ++ tail sat
```

was my attempt to delete only the first member (haven't peaked at D.L yet).

It's unclear which behavior the top poster wants.